# C++ Resolving the diamond problem

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

Couldn't the diamond problem be resolved just by using the first inherited declaration found? I mean,

```
public class A {
    public virtual int getInt();
};

public class B : public A {
    public int getInt() {return 6;}
};

public class C : public A {
    public int getInt() {return 7;}
};

public class D: public B, public C {};
```

for `class D`, since `B` is listed first, couldn't we just by *default* (when it's ambiguous) use `B::getInt()` if `D::getInt()` is called? Kind of how the PATH environment variable works in UNIX and other OS's; if two things exist with the same name in different locations in the PATH variable, then the first location shall be used by default (unless otherwise qualified).

Edit: by 'first' inherited declaration found I mean according to simple left-to-right depth-first order

Edit#2: Just updated the above implementation to be more diamond-like.

Comment: there is no diamond problem here, looks like plain old multiple-inheritance

Comment: also, what if someone accidentally changed the order to `B` `A` `C`? Or derived using that order in some other class - it's very fragile..

Comment: Isn't the underlying issue here that any virtual member in A could have different implementations in B or C and that there's no way to resolve those differences in D, as that would pretty much require that the compiler knew exactly what you wanted to get done (which would defeat the purpose of programmers).

Comment: Resolving ambiguities by arbitrarily guessing what the programmer meant is likely to result in code that doesn't behave as the programmer intended. Forcing the programmer to explicitly state the intended behaviour leaves less room for error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a very buggy solution. Think what will happen in the following case:

```
public class A {
    public int getInt() {return 5;}
    public float getFloat() {return 5.0;}
};

public class B {
    public int getInt() {return 6;}
    public float getFloat() {return 6.0;}
};

public class C {
    public int getInt() {return 7;}
    public float getFloat() {return 7.0;}
};

public class D: public A, public B, public C {}
```

Suppose that one will want `D::getInt` to return 5 while another developer wants `D::getFloat` to return 7.0 (thus, different functions resolved to different ancestors). The second developer will change the order of inheritance and a bug will creep in all code paths depending on `getInt`.

Comment: True, but what if that particular developer group adopts an "**ironclad** coding practice": "DON'T NEVER change the order of inherited classes! (once they are specified)" ?

Are there edge cases even if this rule is *always* followed?

Comment: It's not enforceable. Some day, while desperately trying to fix the bug assigned to him, a developer will do this. And now, he'll have two bugs on the eve of a deadline.

Comment: So other than humans beings != ironclads (@Nim, true indeed!), default left-to-right depth first resolution should otherwise work without problems?

Comment: No, you can have two methods or more involved. And some of they might need other resolution order

Comment: But wouldn't left-to-right depth first resolution order unambiguously resolve the method involved? Also, if someone specifically wanted a different resolution order, couldn't they just instead qualify (with the superclass name) the desired method to be invoked?

Comment: In simple projects it is easy to do this. But in projects with a big codebase the situation is different

Comment: "The second developer will change the order of inheritance": he won't do this since he knows "left-to-right depth first resolution" rule, but will simply define `D::getFloat` to return whatever he wants.

Comment: Happened to projects I was involved twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** a diamond problem. C++ compiler is specific about all its syntax, if there is any ambiguity it will always throw error.

Here your `A::getInt()`, `B::getInt()` and `C::getInt()` are ambiguous when you call simply `d.getInt()`.

**Edit**:

In your edited question, still compiler doesn't evaluate from the inheritance, because some programmers may really need to have different copies of `A`==> 1st via `class B` and 2nd via `class C`. Note that so called **diamond problem** is a problem characterized by humans. For C++ compiler, it's just one more pattern.

In C++ philosophy, you are not restricted to only one paradigm or pattern. You can choose to have multiple inheritance of your choice.